# If I dismiss an Outlook reminder, are they then dismissed for my collegues as well?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, reminder

I manage multiple mailboxes in Outlook (2013). If I dismiss reminders that are intended for my co-workers, does anyone know if they are then also dismissed for their Outlook clients as well, and that (in the worst case) they could miss their appointment? Or are the reminders only dismissed in my local mailbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dismiss a reminder, the bell icon disappears from the calendar entry. If you dismiss the reminder, your colleague will not see it. If the calendar reminder appears on both workstations, the dismissal is immediate for you but will be dismissed automatically after a slight delay.

Comment: Clear answer, thx!